# Double-column DropList / ComboBox in Excel cell without VBA or Form?

Tags: excel

Is there a way in Excel to create DropLists that display 2 columns intead of 1?
I know this can be done in VBA via a Form, but I do not want this file to be macro-enabled and even less to have to resort to a Form; I want the list to be in a cell and to have a whole column with these lists (like a column-wide Data Validation).

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is impossible, here's the workaround I implemented: I created a third column being a join/concat of the other two, so that my DropList shows both column info at the same time.
The small drawback is that when processing the selected value, I need to get only the part I need.
For instance, if my columns are "ID" and "Name", I display "Name [ID]" in the list, and when I retrieve the selected list value to process it in a formula, I get the text between [square brackets] so that I can use the unique identifier while allowing the user to choose a meaningful name in the list instead of an ID they know nothing about.